# ionic 2: import Control shows error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm trying to import Control for email Validator and it shows my error in my project ionic 2 RC0,
this is my code

```
/**
 * Created by adirz on 10/14/2016.
 */

import { Control } from '@angular/common';
export class EmailValidator {

  static isValid(control:  Control) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(control.value);

    if (re) {
      return null;
    }

    return {"invalidEmail": true};
  }
}
```

it shows error when i'm import Control

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) instead of Control like this-

```
import { FormControl }  from '@angular/forms'
```

Also, you can consider AbstractControl (super class of FormControl)